# Only get hash value using md5sum (without filename)

Tags: bash, shell, md5sum

I use [md5sum](https://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum) to generate a hash value for a file.
But I only need to receive the hash value, not the file name.

```
md5=`md5sum ${my_iso_file}`
echo ${md5}
```

Output:

```
3abb17b66815bc7946cefe727737d295  ./iso/somefile.iso
```

How can I 'strip' the file name and only retain the value?

Comment: Very surprising this isn't an option for md5sum.

Comment: Agreed!  *Why* isn't this an option?  Can a GNU-Master shed some light?

Comment: Why do you need to have a "only hash" flag when you can trim the result with some regex? (I am sarcastic)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Using [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
md5=`md5sum ${my_iso_file} | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

Comment: Wrong it gives following output on Mac `MD5 (/Users/hello.txt) = 24811012be8faa36c8f487bbaaadeb71` and your code returns `MD5`.

Comment: You can get run of `-` by adding `| awk '{print $1}'` end of your code => `md5sum < ${my_iso_file} | awk '{print $1}'` @ChristopheDeTroyer

Answer (score 259):

A simple array assignment works... Note that the first element of a Bash array can be addressed by just the `name` without the `[0]` index, i.e., `$md5` contains only the 32 characters of [md5sum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum).

```
md5=($(md5sum file))
echo $md5
# 53c8fdfcbb60cf8e1a1ee90601cc8fe2
```

Comment: Awesome. Just one question, I know the question is tagged `bash`, but can you tell me if array is a bash only feature or some shell standard?

Comment: the first line doesn't work inside the do section of a for loop...as a Bash newb I don't yet know why

Comment: @Andy: If you try this line of code (in the terminal, or in a script): `echo>file; for i in file; do md5=($(md5sum file)); echo $md5; done` - It should output `68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940`

Comment: @Peter.O that does, I figured out that the problem was I had `#!/bin/sh` at the top of my script instead of `#!/bin/bash`.  Thanks!

Comment: How come `echo ($(echo -n foo | md5sum))` doesn't work? Errors out 
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token $(echo -n foo | md5sum)'`

Comment: @lkraav: The *command* `echo -n foo | md5sum` outputs 2 shell *words* to *stdout*: `acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8` and `-` (the `-` indicates the source as *stdin*).  –  You must tell *bash* to capture those *words* into a string, using *Command Substitution*: `$( command )`.  –
The `(` brackets `)` produce a *bash array* with 2 elements. However, you must assign that array construct `( … )` to an variable name; hence, using *md5* as the array name: `md5=($(echo -n foo | md5sum))`. You haven't assigned the array to a variable name

Comment: This is a bash question, but note that this doesn't work in zsh. Instead you can `echo $md5[1]` to get only the hash (but this isn't portable to bash)...

Comment: SO: Searching how to create a md5 hash of a file, learning the shortcut access of the first array element. Thanks :)

Comment: To make the script a bit more bulletproof make sure to set `IFS` explicitly in case it is set to some non-standard value:
`IFS=" " md5=($(md5sum file))`

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it doesn't work in Jenkins

Answer (score 87):

You can use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to split the line on spaces and return only the first such field:

```
md5=$(md5sum "$my_iso_file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

Comment: @CzarekTomczak True, but just by using this answer's method, you could reuse it with different hashing algorithms just by changing the command itself.
`md5sum` -> `sha256sum` without remembering what amount of characters you need to "cut".

Answer (score 32):

On Mac OS X:

```
md5 -q file
```

Comment: doesn't work on my Mac OS X 10.7. But thanks for posting, for whatever version this works on.

Comment: Also `gmd5sum` from `coreutils` would work on MacOS like `md5sum` in other answers mentioned here.

Comment: It worked for me on version `11.5.2` but after removing the `-q` option

Comment: `md5` is different from `md5sum`, which is what OP asked about.

Answer (score 17):

```
md5="$(md5sum "${my_iso_file}")"
md5="${md5%% *}" # remove the first space and everything after it
echo "${md5}"
```

Comment: Nice. One note -- on the first line you don't need quotes around `$()` (although they do no harm) but certainly need them around `${}`.

Comment: @Roman: yeah, I tend to habitually quote any expansion (unless there's a reason not to) -- it's easier than keeping track of the cases where it's safe to skip the quotes.  (Although in this case, I left them off the actual filename... stand by for an edit.)

Answer (score 14):

Another way is to do:

```
md5sum filename | cut -f 1 -d " "
```

[cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)) will split the line to each space and return only the first field.

Answer (score 11):

By leaning on `head`:

```
md5_for_file=`md5sum ${my_iso_file}|head -c 32`
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need to print it and don't need a newline, you can use:

```
printf $(md5sum filename)
```

Answer (score 6):

One way:

```
set -- $(md5sum $file)
md5=$1
```

Another way:

```
md5=$(md5sum $file | while read sum file; do echo $sum; done)
```

Another way:

```
md5=$(set -- $(md5sum $file); echo $1)
```

(Do not try that with backticks unless you're very brave and very good with backslashes.)

The advantage of these solutions over other solutions is that they only invoke `md5sum` and the shell, rather than other programs such as `awk` or `sed`.  Whether that actually matters is then a separate question; you'd probably be hard pressed to notice the difference.

Comment: The question is tagged with Bash, but perhaps indicate how much of this is Bash-specific (e.g., would it work in [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (now allegedly the ***default shell*** in [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina) and later)).

Answer (score 3):

```
md5=$(md5sum < $file | tr -d ' -')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
md5=`md5sum ${my_iso_file} | cut -b-32`
```

Answer (score 1):

`md5sum` puts a backslash before the hash if there is a backslash in the file name. The first 32 characters or anything before the first space may not be a proper hash.

It will not happen when using standard input (file name will be just `-`), so [pixelbeat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679296/only-get-hash-value-using-md5sum-without-filename/3686078#3686078) will work, but many others will require adding something like `| tail -c 32`.

Answer (score 1):

if you're concerned about screwy filenames :

> ```
> md5sum < "${file_name}" | awk NF=1
> ```

```
f244e67ca3e71fff91cdf9b8bd3aa7a5
```

other messier ways to deal with this :

> ```
> md5sum "${file_name}" | awk NF=NF OFS= FS=' .*$' 
>                      or
>                       | awk '_{ exit }++_' RS=' '
> ```

```
f244e67ca3e71fff91cdf9b8bd3aa7a5
```

to do it entirely inside `awk` :

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN {
>     __ = ARGV[ --ARGC ]
>      _ = sprintf("%c",(_+=(_^=_<_)+_)^_+_*++_) 
>     RS = FS
>     gsub(_,"&\\\\&",__)
>
>     ( _=" md5sum < "((_)(__)_) ) | getline
>
>     print $(_*close(_)) }' "${file_name}"
> ```

```
f244e67ca3e71fff91cdf9b8bd3aa7a5
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem today, but I was trying to get the file MD5 hash when running the `find` command.

I got the most voted question and wrapped it in a function called `md5` to run in the `find` command. The mission for me was to calculate the hash for all files in a folder and output it as `hash:filename`.

```
md5() { md5sum $1 | awk '{ printf "%s",$1 }'; }
export -f md5
find -type f -exec bash -c 'md5 "$0"' {} \; -exec echo -n ':' \; -print
```

So, I'd got some pieces from here and also from *['find -exec' a shell function in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321456/find-exec-a-shell-function-in-linux)*

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, a way with sed using a regular expression and a capture group:

```
md5=$(md5sum "${my_iso_file}" | sed -r 's:\\*([^ ]*).*:\1:')
```

The regular expression is capturing everything in a group until a space is reached. To get a capture group working, you need to capture everything in sed.

(More about sed and capture groups here: *[How can I output only captured groups with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777579/how-can-i-output-only-captured-groups-with-sed/2778096#2778096)*)

As delimiter in sed, I use colons because they are not valid in file paths and I don't have to escape the slashes in the filepath.

Comment: Why capture? You can simply delete the space and what is behind:   `sed 's: .*::'` does the same thing!

Answer (score -2):

```
md5=$(md5sum < index.html | head -c -4)
```

Comment: Strange that this was downvoted. I prefer the other answer using `head` - the first 32 characters. But still...

Answer (score -3):

Another way:

```
md5=$(md5sum ${my_iso_file} | sed '/ .*//' )
```

Comment: missing a character:

sed 's/ .*//'