# While loop stops reading after the first line in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, while-loop

I have the following shell script. The purpose is to loop thru each line of the target file (whose path is the input parameter to the script) and do work against each line. Now, it seems only work with the very first line in the target file and stops after that line got processed. Is there anything wrong with my script?

```
#!/bin/bash
# SCRIPT: do.sh
# PURPOSE: loop thru the targets 

FILENAME=$1
count=0

echo "proceed with $FILENAME"

while read LINE; do
   let count++
   echo "$count $LINE"
   sh ./do_work.sh $LINE
done < $FILENAME

echo "\ntotal $count targets"
```

In `do_work.sh`, I run a couple of `ssh` commands.

Comment: Are you sure it's exactly the code that stops after the first line?

Comment: Your script is fine, but there might be something wrong with the do_work.sh

Comment: Yes, it could eat up all input, or it could be invoked as `source` and simply exit or `exec`. But this code doesn't look genuine, the OP would notice that echo requires `-e` to display line feed properly...

Comment: Does `do_work.sh` run `ssh` by any chance?

Comment: yes, do_work.sh runs a couple ssh commands. anything special about that?

Comment: Better you show the `do_work.sh` source and also run `do.sh` with `set -x` to debug.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

The problem is that `do_work.sh` runs `ssh` commands and by default `ssh` reads from stdin which is your input file. As a result, you only see the first line processed, because the command consumes the rest of the file and your while loop terminates.

This happens not just for `ssh`, but for any command that reads stdin, including `mplayer`, `ffmpeg`, `HandBrakeCLI`, `httpie`, `brew install`, and more.

To prevent this, pass the `-n` option to your `ssh` command to make it read from `/dev/null` instead of stdin. Other commands have similar flags, or you can universally use `< /dev/null`.

Comment: Very useful, helped me to run this zsh oneliner: cat hosts | while read host ; do ssh $host do_something ; done

Comment: @rat You still want to avoid the [useless `cat`.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) You'd think a rodent in particular would be wary of this.

Comment: `while read host ; do $host do_something ; done < /etc/hosts` would avoid it. That's quite a life saver, thanks!

Comment: `httpie` is another command that reads STDIN by default, and will suffer from the same behavior when called inside a bash or fish loop. Use `http --ignore-stdin` or set standard input to `/dev/null` as above.

Comment: What will be the solution for `gcloud compute ssh` case?

Answer (score 63):

A very simple and robust workaround is to change the *file descriptor* from which the `read` command receives input.

This is accomplished by two modifications: the `-u` argument to `read`, and the redirection operator for `< $FILENAME`.

In BASH, the default file descriptor values (i.e. values for `-u` in `read`) are:

- 0 = stdin
- 1 = stdout
- 2 = stderr

So just choose some other unused file descriptor, like `9` just for fun.

Thus, the following would be the workaround:

```
while read -u 9 LINE; do
   let count++
   echo "$count $LINE"
   sh ./do_work.sh $LINE
done 9< $FILENAME
```

Notice the two modifications:

1. `read` becomes `read -u 9`
2. `< $FILENAME` becomes `9< $FILENAME`

As a best practice, I do this for all `while` loops I write in BASH.
If you have nested loops using `read`, use a different *file descriptor* for each one (9,8,7,...).

Comment: Thanks! this is actually the best solution here IMO

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks also like the best solution for me right know because with this one you don't need to find the problematic command if you have larger scripts.

Comment: This is a really nice trick. It can be quite a surprise that arbitrary commands end up reading stdin. In my case it was `sloccount`. This is general solution that doesn't require reading command specific man pages (if any).

Comment: This is IMHO a better solution than the accepted one.  There are other commands besides ssh that read stdin, messing up the while loop.  This solution, to use a different file descriptor, allowed me to keep existing called infrastructure in the loop the same.  This allowed me to avoid having to test interactions with sshpass, or other programs in the loop that might affect stdin.   Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me, saves amended the many ssh commands i had.
Although i tried the preferred solution of Dogbane,  adding the -n and </dev/null also worked in my case, but i prefer this one as its just changing the while loop. A very tidy solution that i will try to commit to memory!

Comment: The `-u` option to `read` is a bashism; to make this portable to shells other than bash, just use `while read LINE <&9; do`.

Answer (score 35):

More generally, a workaround which isn't specific to `ssh` is to redirect standard input for any command which might otherwise consume the `while` loop's input.

```
while read -r line; do
   ((count++))
   echo "$count $line"
   sh ./do_work.sh "$line" </dev/null
done < "$filename"
```

The addition of `</dev/null` is the crucial point here, though the corrected quoting is also somewhat important for robustness; see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642). You will want to use `read -r` unless you specifically require the slightly odd legacy behavior you get for backslashes in the input without `-r`. Finally, [avoid upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Another workaround of sorts which is somewhat specific to `ssh` is to make sure any `ssh` command has its standard input tied up, e.g. by changing

```
ssh otherhost some commands here
```

to instead read the commands from a here document, which conveniently (for this particular scenario) ties up the standard input of `ssh` for the commands:

```
ssh otherhost <<'____HERE'
    some commands here
____HERE
```

Answer (score 5):

ssh -n option prevents checking the exit status of ssh when using HEREdoc while piping output to another program.
So use of /dev/null as stdin is preferred.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read ONELINE ; do
   ssh ubuntu@host_xyz </dev/null <<EOF 2>&1 | filter_pgm 
   echo "Hi, $ONELINE. You come here often?"
   process_response_pgm 
EOF
   if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ] ; then
      echo "aborting loop"
      exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
   fi
done << input_list.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  The `<<EOF` overrides the `</dev/null` redirection. The `<<` redirection after the `done` is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This was happening to me because I had `set -e` and a `grep` in a loop was returning with no output (which gives a non-zero error code).

Comment: You beauty, just saved my afternoon

Comment: Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script for more details about `set -e`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I was not reading from a file but from a bash variable containing some `csv` data, so the file descriptor thing did not work for me.
My solution was to feed some empty input into the program that was stealing data from `stdin` via
`echo -n | input_stealing_program`

Example:

```bash
csv_data="Germany,Berlin
France,Paris
Enland,London"

# Set IFS to comma for parsing CSV
IFS=','

while read -r country capital; do
    echo -n | input_stealing_programm $country $capital
done <<< "$csv_data"
```

An alternative would be `input_stealing_program < /dev/null`