# Get Application Name/ Label via ADB Shell or Terminal

Tags: android, shell, label, adb

I'm developing an application that uses ADB Shell to interface with android devices, and I need some way of printing out the application name or label of an application, given maybe their package name.

In short, I need a way of getting app names (i.e. "Angry Birds v1.0.0") for user installed applications through `adb shell`.

Any light on the matter? Any help is appreciated on this.

Answer (score 94):

`adb shell pm list packages` will give you a list of all installed package names.

You can then use `dumpsys | grep -A18 "Package \[my.package\]"` to grab the package information such as version identifiers etc

Comment: why dump all services when you only need `dumpsys package packages`? also no need to grep - dumpsys package supports filtering by package name

Comment: I know of that command, and sure, it's a start, giving me the package names of all installed applications. 

I've tried using dumpsys, but to not much success, leaving me to believe that I may not be using it right. Does it only work on running applications? or does it work on ones that haven't been launched at all as well.

Also, could I get a usage example just in case? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As per above, I managed to get the above code working to dumping package information, however it does not give me the data that I'm looking for. I'm referring to something similar to `aapt d badging` where I'd get information like `application-label: ES File Explorer` and `versionName='1.6.2.5'`. Is there anything that can give me this information through shell?

Comment: @hamsteyr Any success meanwhile? If so: you can answer your own question. I'll certainly upvote then if your solution works (currently looking for the same) ;)

Comment: This answer is not working. `dumpsys` does not output any text matching or nearby "Package [package.name]" that helps determine the app's label. appLabel is listed by `dumpsys package`, but only for a few apps ("BusyBox Pro", "BusyBox", and " ES File Manager" are some of the 5ish I get). Anyone have another solution?

Comment: windows users can use **findstr** instead of grep `adb shell pm list packages | findstr -s "package:com.twitter.android"`

Comment: Command `pm list` has been moved to `cmd package`, use `adb shell cmd package list packages` to list all installed package names in newer version.

Comment: @o0rebelious0o Cannot find the full application name of the [com.akh.livestream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akh.livestream) package from your `dumpsys | grep -A18 "Package \[my.package\]"`

Comment: This no longer works as tested on Android 11.

Answer (score 31):

just enter the following command on command prompt after launching the app:

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | find "mCurrentFocus"
```

if executing the command on linux terminal replace find by grep

Comment: variable `mCurrentFocus` does not exist in the output of `adb shell dumpsys window windows` so find or grep return nothing

Comment: I used `"topApp"` instead of `"mCurrentFocus"`

Comment: use `grep` if `find` didn't work on the above solution.

Comment: I find useful this one: `adb shell dumpsys window windows | find "package"`

Comment: what if no grep in windows environment?

Comment: @gumuruh You can use "find" on windows platform which is equivalent for "grep" on Unix / Linux platform

Comment: The reason for using "mCurrentFocus" is because of the Android version. Once the android version changes, or if the OEM thinks of restructuring, this string could change ==> mCurrentFocus

Answer (score 13):

If you know the app id of the package (like org.mozilla.firefox), it is easy.
First to get the path of actual package file of the appId,

```
$  adb shell pm list packages -f com.google.android.apps.inbox
package:/data/app/com.google.android.apps.inbox-1/base.apk=com.google.android.apps.inbox
```

Now you can do some grep|sed magic to extract the path : `/data/app/com.google.android.apps.inbox-1/base.apk`

After that aapt tool comes in handy :

```
$  adb shell aapt dump badging /data/app/com.google.android.apps.inbox-1/base.apk
...
application-label:'Inbox'
application-label-hi:'Inbox'
application-label-ru:'Inbox'
...
```

Again some grep magic to get the Label.

Comment: That last command won't work because aapt is only on your developer machine. You'll need to pull the apk from the device first.

Comment: Even if you use it on the local machine the argument after "-f" acts like a wildcard, so if there are more than one package containing that string it will show several packages. The best way to do it is:
`adb shell pm list packages -f` and then filter out the result.

Answer (score 4):

A shell script to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove whitespace
function remWS {
    if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
        cat | tr -d '[:space:]'
    else
        echo "${1}" | tr -d '[:space:]'
    fi
}

for pkg in $(adb shell pm list packages -3 | cut -d':' -f2); do
    apk_loc="$(adb shell pm path $(remWS $pkg) | cut -d':' -f2 | remWS)"
    apk_name="$(adb shell aapt dump badging $apk_loc | pcregrep -o1 $'application-label:\'(.+)\'' | remWS)"
    apk_info="$(adb shell aapt dump badging $apk_loc | pcregrep -o1 '\b(package: .+)')"

    echo "$apk_name v$(echo $apk_info | pcregrep -io1 -e $'\\bversionName=\'(.+?)\'')"
done
```

Comment: This just prints empty lines with "v" in it

Answer (score 3):

Inorder to find an app's name (application label), you need to do the following:
(as shown in other answers)

1. Find the APK path of the app whose name you want to find.
2. Using `aapt` command, find the app label.

But devices don't ship with the `aapt` binary out-of-the-box.
So you will need to install it first. You can download it from here:
https://github.com/Calsign/APDE/tree/master/APDE/src/main/assets/aapt-binaries

---

Check this guide for complete steps:
[How to find an app name using package name through ADB Android?](https://gokulnc.github.io/blog/find-app-name-adb/)
(*Disclaimer*: I am the author of that blog post)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I just came up with. It gives a few errors but works well enough for my needs, matching package names to labels.

It pulls copies of all packages into subdirectories of $PWD, so keep that in mind if storage is a concern.

```
#!/bin/bash
TOOLS=~/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130717/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0
AAPT=$TOOLS/aapt
PMLIST=adb_shell_pm_list_packages_-f.txt
TEMP=$(echo $(adb shell mktemp -d -p /data/local/tmp) | sed 's/\r//')
mkdir -p packages
[ -f $PMLIST ] || eval $(echo $(basename $PMLIST) | tr '_' ' ') > $PMLIST
while read line; do
 package=${line##*:}
 apk=${package%%=*}
 name=${package#*=}
 copy=packages$apk
 mkdir -p $(dirname $copy)
 if [ ! -s $copy ]; then  # copy it because `adb pull` doesn't see /mnt/expand/
  adb shell cp -f $apk $TEMP/copy.apk
  adb pull $TEMP/copy.apk $copy
 fi
 label=$($AAPT dump badging $copy || echo ERROR in $copy >&2 | \
  sed -n 's/^application-label:\(.\)\(.*\)\1$/\2/p')
 echo $name:$label
done < <(sed 's/\r//' $PMLIST)
adb shell rm -rf $TEMP
```

Answer (score 1):

So I extremely grateful to jcomeau_ictx for providing the info on how to extract application-label info from apk and the idea to pull apk from phone directly!
However I had to make several alteration to script it self:

1. `while read line; do done` are breaking as a result of commands within while loop interacting with stdin/stdout and as a result while loop runs only once and then stops, as it is discussed in [While loop stops reading after the first line in Bash - the comment from cmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash/66179139#66179139) I used solution provided and switched while loop to use unused file descriptor number 9.
2. All that the script really need is a package name and `adb shell pm list packages -f` is really excessive so I changed it to expect a file with packages list only and provided example on how one can get one from adb.
3. jcomeau_ictx script variant do not take in to account that some packages may have multiple apk associated with them which breaks the script.
4. And the least and last, I made every variable to start with underscore, it's just something that makes it easier to read script.

So here another variant of the same script:

```
#!/bin/bash
_TOOLS=/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/build-tools/29.0.3
_AAPT=${_TOOLS}/aapt
#adb shell pm list packages --user 0 | sed -e 's|^package:||' | sort >./packages_list.txt
_PMLIST=packages_list.txt
rm ./packages_list_with_names.txt
_TEMP=$(echo $(adb shell mktemp -d -p /data/local/tmp) | sed 's/\r//')
mkdir -p packages
[ -f ${_PMLIST} ] || eval $(echo $(basename ${_PMLIST}) | tr '_' ' ') > ${_PMLIST}
while read -u 9 _line; do
    _package=${_line##*:}
    _apkpath=$(adb shell pm path ${_package} | sed -e 's|^package:||' | head -n 1)
    _apkfilename=$(basename "${_apkpath}")
    adb shell cp -f ${_apkpath} ${_TEMP}/copy.apk
    adb pull ${_TEMP}/copy.apk ./packages
    _name=$(${_AAPT} dump badging ./packages/copy.apk | sed -n 's|^application-label:\(.\)\(.*\)\1$|\2|p' )
#'
    echo "${_package} - ${_name}" >>./packages_list_with_names.txt
done 9< ${_PMLIST}
adb shell rm -rf $TEMP
```

Comment: What about `sed --silent --regexp-extended "s/^application-label:'(.*)'$/\1/p"`? I think, it's easier to understand (I mean single quotes in clear text). And thank you for your script enhancements.

Comment: Yes, that's also works, about easy to read, all depends on what you used to, for me it's easier to read with shielding backslash.