# Android: Get the stack (array) of currently opened applications

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to get the list of the currently running or opened android applications, so that I can found the last application running in the device. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was working on an emoji keyboard from fast few days. It take me three days to get the foreground application package name to send the emoji images, as whenever I want to send the images it just popups the `intentchooser` to choose one of the application those can handle the images as extras.

All the tutorials and links does not work for me as google deprecated the `getRunningTasks()` method that was used to get the currently running applications.

Then I got an idea to get the stack of the currently running applications on the device using `ResolveInfo`, but it did not work too.

Finally, I found a new class introduced in API 21 named `UsageStatsManager` which worked for me. [This github link](https://github.com/ColeMurray/UsageStatsSample/tree/master/app/src/main) provide how to use this class to get the running applications packagename.

Below is my code how I got the package name application running on the top:

```
public class UStats {
    public static final String TAG = UStats.class.getSimpleName();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    public static ArrayList<String> printCurrentUsageStatus(Context context) {
        return printUsageStats(getUsageStatsList(context));
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public static ArrayList<String> printUsageStats(List<UsageStats> usageStatsList) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> lastApp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (UsageStats u : usageStatsList) {
            lastApp.put(u.getPackageName(), (int) u.getLastTimeStamp());
            /*Log.d(TAG, "Pkg: " + u.getPackageName() + "\t" + "ForegroundTime: "
                    + u.getTotalTimeInForeground() + "\t" + "LastTimeStamp: " + new Date(u.getLastTimeStamp()));*/
        }
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMapAsc = sortByComparator(lastApp);
        ArrayList<String> firstApp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMapAsc.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            //Integer value = entry.getValue();
            firstApp.add(key);
            /*System.out.println("package name: " + key + ", time " + new Date(Math.abs(value)));*/
        }

        return firstApp;
    }

    // To check the USAGE_STATS_SERVICE permission
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public static List<UsageStats> getUsageStatsList(Context context) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = getUsageStatsManager(context);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
        long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        Log.d(TAG, "Under getUsageStateList");
        Log.d(TAG, "Range start:" + dateFormat.format(startTime));
        Log.d(TAG, "Range end:" + dateFormat.format(endTime));

        List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, endTime);
        return usageStatsList;
    }

    // Sort the map in the ascending order of the timeStamp
    private static Map<String, Integer> sortByComparator(Map<String, Integer> unsortMap) {
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>(unsortMap.entrySet());

        // Sorting the list based on values
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                               Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });

        // Maintaining insertion order with the help of LinkedList
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return sortedMap;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    private static UsageStatsManager getUsageStatsManager(Context context) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        return usm;
    }
}
```

Then I simply get the ArrayList of the application package names, using the below code:

```
ArrayList<String> sortedApplication = UStats.printCurrentUsageStatus(SimpleIME.this);
Log.d("TAG", "applicationList: " + sortedApplication.toString());
```

Don't forgot to add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
                     tools:ignore = "ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

and the below code to check that our application has the permission to get the other applications status:

```
if (UStats.getUsageStatsList(this).isEmpty()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enable Usage Access for YOUR_APP_NAME to use this app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The above code will open a access setting page to enable our application to get the other application usage stats (for once).

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

I use this block of code to see the actual list of package names install in the system:

```
            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm list packages");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                         new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                int read;
                char[] buffer = new char[4096];
                StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

                while ((read = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    output.append(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                process.waitFor();

                Log.d("your tag", output.toString());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am sure that through the package and the PID you can adapt a command in the ADB shell console to find the time information about apps list, but I don't think you can see the last application open on the system, although I don't know all the commands that the shell console uses...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1 -d 1");
```

For example, this command shows the different processes and their consumption of resources within the device.

Meet them in the following documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line

Related:

- [Get Application Name/ Label via ADB Shell or Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650765/get-application-name-label-via-adb-shell-or-terminal)

Answer (score -2):

If you want it to be more reactive I actually just tackle a similar scenario via LiveData. Check out my blog post about it: https://bmcreations.dev/blog/foreground-app-observing-with-lifecycle-components

Comment: Why was this -1?