# Android, how to get app on foreground

Tags: android, service, foreground

I'm trying to develop a service that whenever an user opens an app my service will identify it. I'm using the files: /proc/[pid]/cgroup,/proc/[pid]/cmdline,/proc/[pid]/oom_score,/proc/[pid]/oom_score_adj to check if it's an user app running on foreground. Actually it's working but when I try to open any game the service won't recognize it all the time. (The service only identify the files (oom_score) that has the lowest value).

Example: oom_score for "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor" is 75, but for "com.king.candycrushsaga" will be >150, so it will never be detected by the code (as it follows).

Service code:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        s=appManager.getAppRunningForeground();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
},1,2,SECONDS);
```

Function that gets the app running:

```
private ReadWriteFile readWriteFile = new ReadWriteFile();
public String getAppRunningForeground(){
    int pid;
    File[] files = new File("/proc").listFiles();
    int lowestOomScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String foregroundProcess = null;
    for (File file : files) {
        if (!file.isDirectory() || (!file.getName().matches(("\\d+"))))
            continue;
        pid = Integer.parseInt(file.getName());
        try {
            String cgroup = readWriteFile.read(String.format("/proc/%d/cgroup", pid));
            String[] lines = cgroup.split("\n");
            if (lines.length != 2)
                continue;
            String cpuSubsystem = lines[0];
            String cpuaccctSubsystem = lines[1];
            if (!cpuaccctSubsystem.endsWith(Integer.toString(pid)) || cpuSubsystem.endsWith("bg_non_interactive"))
                continue;
            String cmdline = readWriteFile.read(String.format("/proc/%d/cmdline", pid));
            if (cmdline.contains("com.android.systemui")||cmdline.contains("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor")) {
                continue;
            }
            int uid = Integer.parseInt(cpuaccctSubsystem.split(":")[2].split("/")[1].replace("uid_", ""));
            if (uid > 1000 && uid <= 1038)//System process
                continue;
            File oomScoreAdj = new File(String.format("/proc/%d/oom_score_adj", pid));
            if (oomScoreAdj.canRead()) {
                int oomAdj = Integer.parseInt(readWriteFile.read(oomScoreAdj.getAbsolutePath()));
                if (oomAdj != 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            int oomscore = Integer.parseInt(readWriteFile.read(String.format("/proc/%d/oom_score", pid)));
            if (oomscore < lowestOomScore) {
                lowestOomScore = oomscore;
                foregroundProcess = cmdline.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return foregroundProcess;
}
```

Class that reads a file.

```
public class ReadWriteFile{
    File file;
    StringBuilder teste3 = new StringBuilder();
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    public static String read(String path) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        output.append(reader.readLine());
        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
            output.append('\n').append(line);
        reader.close();
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

P.S: getRunningTasks is deprecated, so please, don't suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UsageStatsManager` class added in android api 21. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197811/android-get-the-stack-array-of-currently-opened-applications/38265990#38265990)
question raised and answered by [me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6389301/lradha).

The above answer will provide you an sorted applications ArrayList, required foreground application will the first one in the ArrayList on the index number 0.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I really thanks to **Mr. Gagan Deep** who mailed me at 1:30 AM about this class, when I was hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

This methods help you

```
  void checkForegroundAppCompat()
        {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
            final ComponentName componentName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if(!getWhiteListedPackages().contains(componentName.getPackageName()) &&
                    SecurityStatusManager.isAppsBlockingEnabled(this))
            {
                int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName(componentName.getPackageName());
// Kill blick APP here               
  GRLog.w("KILL Blacklist App Package: " + componentName.getPackageName() + " with pid: " + pid);
                killApp(componentName.getPackageName(), pid);
            }
        }
```

Comment: getRunningTasks is deprecated as I said