# How to systematically get common android app name on device via adb

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to figure out a way to get a list of apps on an android connected device.  I am able to get the bundle name but would like to figure out a way to get the "human friendly readable name"

I can get the bundle names via

```
adb shell pm list packages -3
```

returns package names like: com.awesomeapps.thebestapp

However, I have not yet figured out a way to map / query / locate the associated "human friendly name" of the app.

Is there a way to do this with adb?  Is there another way to get this "human friendly" name?

In summary

can get:
bundle id: com.abcdisneyf.com

can't get
real bundle name: "Freeform"

Comment: If you don't find an easier way you can sill download the base APK of each package in the list, extract it's `AndroidManifest.xml` (which usually contains a reference to a localized string) and the appropriate localized strings.xml from resources and thus you have the App name.

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/90141/obtain-package-name-and-common-name-of-apps-via-adb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650765/get-application-name-label-via-adb-shell-or-terminal contains a working solution (assuming you're using aapt from your PC)