# Shell script not able to parse host list and host unknown

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a script that I am trying to run. The purpose of this script is to run single or multiple commands on list of servers. When running it, the script is not able to parse the hosts file and gives an error:

> ssh: Could not resolve host name nodename nor servname provided, or not known

```
while read host;
do
echo server: $host
sshpass -p 'password'   ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" admin@$host  'command'
done < /path/to/hosts.txt
```

`hosts.txt` contains list of IP addresses of the hosts that need to connect in the following format:

```
server 1
server 2
server 3
```

I have tried putting the server IPs in `""` and `''` and `;` and `,`, but they all give the same error.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Make sure your system can resolve the hostnames. No ssh problem. For your next problem: Add option `-n` to your ssh command.

Comment: i can log into each hosts via ssh from my system and can resolve to hostname perfectly fine, but when i enter list of server IPs, the script is only able to do the first ip and run the command on the first IP on the list but does not parse the rest of the list.

Comment: You appear to have posted a redacted pseudo-code version of your script along with dummy data and censored output. This makes it hard to debug. Can you please create a new script that doesn't have any code or data you need to hide, then run it and post the complete, unmodified script and all its output?

Comment: Check hosts.txt for special characters (DOS/Windows line breaks): `cat -A hosts.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus no special characters are in the hosts file. for some reason, it reads the first host and executes the command on the first host and then stops reading the rest of the hosts.

Comment: What is with your `ssh: Could not resolve host name nodename nor servname provided, or not known` problem?

Comment: so when i make a list of IP's only on each line in hosts.txt and run the script, it gives me that error. but when i put the hostname and then ip on each line, it reads the first server and runs the command and does not run the next server but it doesnt give me the above error.

Comment: Please follow [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273400/shell-script-not-able-to-parse-host-list-and-host-unknown?noredirect=1#comment102913994_58273400)'s instructions.

Comment: Part of the problem may be due to `ssh` reading stdin, thus bogarting the file list. See ["Shell script while read line loop stops after the first line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/shell-script-while-read-line-loop-stops-after-the-first-line) and [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: or see my first comment.

Comment: @Cyrus and @Gordon Davisson thank you `-n` resolved the issue. such a simple fix i am surprised i didnt see that post here before despite of lot of searching. guess i wasnt wording it the right way. Thank all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if $host variable is getting parsed properly. Also, in your hosts.txt, there are two entries in each row. What does it signify?

I have created a sample script to parse space-separated arguments

Input file: hosts.txt

[image]

Script output:

[image]

```
#!bin/sh
while IFS=' ', read hostname ipaddress;
do
echo server: $ipaddress
done < hosts.txt
```

Comment: I tried your script and it works to echo the results and then i added what i actually wanted to do with the script with the command for multiple servers and  for some reason, it reads the first host and executes the command on the first host and then stops reading the rest of the hosts.

Comment: i tried doing this and its working but not when i tell it to parse the list

 ```hosts="ip1 ip2 ip3 ip4"
for HOSTNAME in ${hosts};
do```

Answer (score 0):

@Cyrus and @Gordon Davisson thank you -n resolved the issue. such a simple fix i am surprised i didnt see that post here before despite of lot of searching. guess i wasnt wording it the right way. Thank all for the input.