# Removing a remote file through ssh stops the while loop the command is in?

Tags: bash, ssh, rm

I have this script that lists files having been modified more than 10minutes ago on a remote disk, retrieve them locally, and then, is supposed to delete them on remote.
The script works when I don't remove the files.
As soon as I add the line to remove the files, the loop is only processed once (only one file is successfully copied, and I have the message confirming it is in local disk), and then the loop stops without any error message.
Please, any idea why?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

S_ACCOUNTS=('yohplala')
RMT_IP='88.214.320.588'
LOC_PATH_DATA='../data/cs_remote/'
MOD_TIME='+10'                      # Last modification time, in minutes

# List, copy, delete files.
for serv_account in "${S_ACCOUNTS[@]}"; do
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
        scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@$RMT_IP:"$file" "$LOC_PATH_DATA""$serv_account"
        if test -f "$LOC_PATH_DATA""$serv_account"'/'"$(basename "$file")"; then
            echo "$(basename "$file")"' successfully copied.'
            ssh root@$RMT_IP "rm $file"                          # <= troublesome line here
        fi
    done < <(ssh root@$RMT_IP "find "/root/test" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin $MOD_TIME -print0")
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `ssh` reads from stdin which is your input file and `ssh` consumes the rest of the file and your `for` loop terminates.

To prevent this, pass the `-n` option to your ssh command to make it read from `/dev/null` instead of `stdin`.

From ssh man page:

> -n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the background.  A
> common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote machine.
> For example, ssh -n shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will start an emacs on
> shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will be automatically
> forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh program will be put in
> the background.  (This does not work if ssh needs to ask for a
> password or passphrase; see also the -f option.)

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/shell-script-while-read-line-loop-stops-after-the-first-line) for more.