# SSH authentication verification with Bash Shell script on multiple hosts

Tags: bash, ssh

I know there are other solution such as `expect`, or `Python paramiko`, but `bash shell` is the only option available for now.

Out of these 3 IPs, only `172.16.1.2` has SSH server installed and they have similar password.

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat ip.txt
172.16.1.1
172.16.1.2
172.16.1.3
wolf@linux:~$
```

This is the Bash script

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat sshSession.sh
while read host
do
    export SSH_ASKPASS='~/ePass'
    setsid ssh -T user@$host
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        exit
        echo "$host | SSH Authentication OK"
    else
        echo "$host | SSH Authentication PROBLEM"
    fi
done < ip.txt
wolf@linux:~$
```

Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ ./sshSession.sh
ssh: connect to host 172.16.1.1 port 22: No route to host
172.16.1.1 | SSH Authentication PROBLEM
Welcome to Ubuntu Server

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

-bash: line 1: 172.16.1.3: command not found
172.16.1.2 | SSH Authentication PROBLEM
wolf@linux:~$
```

There are a few problems here.

1. I just want to get the authentication status only, not to log in into the server.
2. There is something wrong with the output `-bash: line 1: 172.16.1.3: command not found`
3. `172.16.1.2 | SSH Authentication PROBLEM` - This is the only host installed with SSH, while others not.

Desired Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ ./sshSession.sh
172.16.1.1 | SSH Authentication PROBLEM
172.16.1.2 | SSH Authentication OK
172.16.1.3 | SSH Authentication PROBLEM
```

What's wrong in the script and how to fix it?

Comment: (OT: **1** You’re missing a shebang. It looks like you’re getting Bash, but there’s no guarantee. **2** `exit ; echo` won’t work. **3** No need to export `SSH_ASKPASS` more than once.)

Comment: `ssh user@host true` should tell you whether you can connect and authenticate, without starting an interactive session.

Comment: Tangentially see also [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: As for the ‘command not found’: _Probably_ a quoting issue (use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)!) and/or some invisible character in the input (e.g. `\r`). Running the script with `bash -x sshSession.sh` (or adding `set -x` at the top of the script) should help you debug.

Comment: Thanks @Biffen, `ssh user@host true` very helpful. I've tested shebang and it doesn't give any difference.

Comment: (@Wolf The shebang won’t _solve_ anything (this time). But it’s a good idea, especially if you want to use the script on an other machine.)

Comment: Thanks @Biffen, I've updated the code and output above. Half of the problems have been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the `exit` gets written into the `ssh` session, but that's not how it works. You execute `exit` after the `ssh` process terminates. See [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc)

Also, you seem to be passing standard input from your `while` loop into the running `ssh` instance.  See [Shell script while read line loop stops after the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/shell-script-while-read-line-loop-stops-after-the-first-line)

Also, [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Also, use `read -r` as a general principle (though I guess it doesn't really matter here).  And don't repeatedly set `SSH_ASKPASS` to the same value. (And generally don't `export` a variable more than once; it's harmless but usually reveals more than you like about your understanding of what `export` actually does.) And, [quote your variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

```sh
export SSH_ASKPASS='~/ePass'
while read -r host
do
    if setsid ssh -T -n user@"$host" true; then
        echo "$host | SSH Authentication OK"
    else
        echo "$host | SSH Authentication PROBLEM"
    fi
done < ip.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, problem solved. Anyway, how do I remove `ssh: connect to host 172.16.1.1 port 22: No route to host` from the output?

Comment: Redirect standard error to `/dev/null` if you don't want to see it.

Comment: Got it, thanks

`if setsid ssh -T -n user@"$host" true 2>/dev/null; then`