# while read line in a file from a specific column

Tags: bash

Just need some help with a while read file from a specific column

I have a file with a few columns and I want to use while loop for a specific column 
`123` `50012` `1111`
 `235` `40023` `2222` 
 `674` `30021` `3333`

```
while read -a  line; do echo -e ${line[0]} > /dev/null;
echo "this is $line"
done < /location/file
```

it gives the correct info

`this is 123`
`this is 235`
`this is 674`

It works fine until I run the script, it stops at first line

`this is 123`

and stops.

If I place the column 0 into a separate file and run it with a script using a different way it works fine.

```
while IFS= read -r -u "$fd_num" line; do
script goes here...
done {fd_num}< /location/file
```

this works great, but I would like to keep everything in one file.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check for windows line endings aka carriage returns from the file in questions.  Also put a shebang on your script and paste it at https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
123 50012 1111
235 40023 2222 
674 30021 3333
```

You can do in Bash (works for tabs or spaces):

```
while read -r -a arr; 
    do printf "%s\n" "${arr[0]}"; # NOTE QUOTING!
done <file
```

If there is a possibility the last line is not properly terminated:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    arr=($line)         #purposefully does not have quoting
    printf "%s\n" "${arr[0]}"; 
done <file
```

Or use `cut` (assuming that is space, `' '`, delimited:

```
cat file | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Or `awk` (space or tabs):

```
awk '{print $1}` file
```

Any of those prints:

```
123
235
674
```

All three work with `\r\n` or `\n` on a unix machine (can't say for Windows...)

Comment: thank you for the response, it works just like mine, but when running script stops at first line. I have made it work fine when that column 0 in a separate file  using `while IFS= read -r -u "$fd_num" line; do`     `done {fd_num}< /location/file` but I would like to have everything in one file.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` command already splits the line based on the separators of $IFS (and with the default IFS, splits on sequences of space/tab).

You can do

```sh
while read -r col1 restOfList; do
    echo "this is $col1"
done < filename
```

Comment: your approach  is fine as well, but it will stop at the first line when reading the file when running the script.

Comment: Uh, no, it will not. Perhaps you have a more complex command inside the loop which eats standard input; then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/shell-script-while-read-line-loop-stops-after-the-first-line

Comment: ok thank you, that would probably be the case