# Unable to Connect to AWS Linux VM using SSH terminal

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh

I'm trying to connect to AWS instance through terminal using SSH with the public IP address and I keep getting:

> Warning: Identity file .cer not accessible: No such file or directory.
> ubuntu@XXXXXXXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).

I'm running this script to remote in, hosts.txt contains the IP address

```
#!/bin/bash
while read HOST INSTANCE_KEY;
do
if ssh -i $INSTANCE_KEY.cer ubuntu@$HOST '
STATUS=`/opt/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print $3 $4}'`
[ "$STATUS" = "isrunning" ]
'; then
echo "$HOST == FAIL"
else
echo "$HOST == PASS"
fi
done < hosts.txt
```

I'm need to SSH to public IP Address using the Authentication Key received from AWS

Comment: It looks to me like you haven't configured the SSH public key correctly in your AWS instance.

Comment: Right. I made the mistake of testing using a wrapper script that doesn't propagate.

Comment: Use `ssh -n` to prevent `ssh` from reading the rest of your `hosts.txt` file and stopping the loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash

Comment: The warning message indicates that `INSTANCE_KEY` isn't set, or else it would be something like `Warning: Identity file foo.cer not accessible...` (if `INSTANCE_KEY` had the value `foo`).

Comment: You likely have a line in the file that contains only a host name, without an associated key file name.