# How to launch a script for a list of ip addresses (bash script)

Tags: bash, shell

i have a problem with my bash shell script. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash/

while read line  
do   
   echo -e "$line
"  
sleep 5;
done < Ip.txt

sshpass -p 'Password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$ip -t "cd /exemple/ && sh restart-launcher.sh;exec \$SHELL -l"
```

My script allows to launch for each ip (Ip.txt) in the folder "exemple" a script(restart-launcher.sh) but when I launch it , it only lists the ip without taking this part into account:

`sshpass -p 'Password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$ip -t "cd /folders/ && sh restart-launcher.sh;exec \$SHELL -l"`

How do I create a bash script that works in Linux?

Comment: Where do you set `$ip`?

Comment: The `sshpass` line isn't inside the loop, so it's only done once when the loop is done.

Comment: And it doesn't make use of `$line`.

Comment: "Where do you set $ip? " it's for the list in ip.txt

Comment: "The sshpass line isn't inside the loop, so it's only done once when the loop is done." how  to do that ? (Srry i just started the bash )

Comment: The variable `ip` is never assigned to. Therefore it is empty. I suggest to put a `set -u` at the start of your script, to catch this kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/bash/
while read -r line; do   
    echo -e "$line\n"
    sshpass -p 'Password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$line -t \
        "cd /exemple/ && sh restart-launcher.sh;exec \$SHELL -l"
    sleep 5
done < Ip.txt
```

Now, we could have a discussion about using sshpass (or rather, why you shouldn't), but it feels out of scope.

So, all commands you wish to be looped over need to be inside the loop.
As you read sets the variable `$line`, that is what you need to use. In your example, you used the variable `$ip` which you haven't set anywhere.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash

Comment: If my answer led to you sorting things out, please set it as the accepted answer @IppoMuto

Comment: hi, @Kaffe Myers , when i run my script, i have this "Name or service not knownname 1.1.1.1", do you know what  the problem is?

Comment: Well, seems you have `1.1.1.1` in your `Ip.txt` file, which I expect to be incorrect, unless you work for cloudflare: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/

If that is not it, then I need more information to have a clue.

Comment: this ip 1.1.1.1 it's an example :)

Comment: Do your ip-file only contain one ip per line?

Comment: Yes only One ip per line

Comment: Are you able to ssh into the IP that brings error with the same command manually?

Comment: Yes i can via ssh

Comment: Well, I can sit and throw questions all day, but you might have a better and faster resolution analysing the debug information in the script. Run it with `bash -x` and see if you can spot the issue.

Comment: ok no problem, thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that "Ip.txt" contains a list of only IPs perhaps what you mean to do is use `sshpass` inside the while-loop so it runs for each IP in the .txt file.

```sh
#!/bin/bash/

while read line  
do   
   echo -e "$line
"  
sshpass -p 'Password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$line -t "cd /exemple/ && sh restart-launcher.sh;exec \$SHELL -l"
sleep 5;
done < Ip.txt
```

`sshpass` has been moved into the while loop and `$ip` replaced with `$line`