# Gcloud compute in the gitlab pipeline loop executed only once

Tags: bash, gitlab, gcloud

I'm trying to run bash script in my GitLab pipeline which looks like:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format=yaml --filter=tags.items:${SERVER_TAG} --format='value(name)' | while IFS= read -r instance_name
do
    instances+=('${instance_name}')
    echo "-----------------------------------"
    echo "L1 Instance Name: ${instance_name}"
    #gcloud compute ssh ${instance_name} --quiet --tunnel-through-iap --zone=us-east4-c --project=${PROJECT_ID} --impersonate-service-account=ci-cd-pipeline@iam.gserviceaccount.com --command="whoami"
    #sleep 60
    echo "==================================="
done

echo ">>1<<"

gcloud compute instances list --format=yaml --filter=tags.items:${SERVER_TAG} --format='value(name)' | while IFS= read -r instance_name
do
    instances+=('${instance_name}')
    echo "-----------------------------------"
    echo "L2 Instance Name: ${instance_name}"
    gcloud compute ssh ${instance_name} --quiet --tunnel-through-iap --zone=us-east4-c --project=${PROJECT_ID} --impersonate-service-account=ci-cd-pipeline@iam.gserviceaccount.com --command="whoami"
    sleep 120
    echo "==================================="
done

echo ">>2<<"
```

First part of it will be executed as expected:

```
-----------------------------------
L1 Instance Name: dev-001
===================================
-----------------------------------
L1 Instance Name: dev-002
===================================
>>1<<
```

but second part of it will only execute once:

```
-----------------------------------
L2 Instance Name: dev-001
(...)
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [ci-cd-pipeline@iam.gserviceaccount.com].
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.8057989512480153153' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
sa_104167209456792997386
===================================
>>2<<
```

Why instance `dev-002` is not getting called by `gcloud compute ssh` by the loop?

PS.
Solution from [While loop stops reading after the first line in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash) is not working for `gcloud compute ssh`. In that case I have opened new more relative questions at [gcloud compute ssh - how to make read from /dev/null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76909561/gcloud-compute-ssh-how-to-make-read-from-dev-null) as above solution is not real solution for closing OP.

Comment: `gcloud compute ssh` undoubtedly behaves the same way `ssh` does, and drains stdin so that the while loop doesn't get anything else as in the duplicate.

Comment: @thatotherguy ok, but provided example as the solution will not work for `gcloud compute ssh`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that problem. The top solution suggests passing `-n` to ssh, or `< /dev/null` generally. The second highest suggests using a different FD to read in the file loop. All three appear to work for `cloud compute ssh` for me. What were your attempts, and how did they fail?

Comment: @thatotherguy adding `-n` error out as `ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) unrecognized arguments: -n `. Adding `< /dev/null` caused pipeline job to stall. I have checked few solutions and adding `sleep 30` just after `glcloud compute ssh` fixed the problem.

Comment: You'd have to use `gcloud compute ssh ... -- -n whoami` as this is how you pass arguments to ssh with gcloud (see `gcloud compute ssh --help`). Adding a sleep after the `gcloud compute ssh` in the loop would not have fixed this particular problem, and I don't know why `< /dev/null` would cause anything to stall. I would really recommend double checking these assertions, but I voted to reopen the question in the mean time.

Comment: @thatotherguy now I see what I have missed - `--` before `-n`. Regarding `< /dev/null` pipeline job stuck on three dots output in the gitlab. Maybe just a bad luck with the gitlab runner yesterday. You can close my question as the dup. Ppl can find all in the comments ;)