# Weird Bash Script behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have designing simple bash script just to process an output of a command that loops based on the number of entries in text file.
I have attached script below:

```
`#!/bin/bash

# Check if at least one argument (server list file) is provided
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 server_list_file"
    exit 1
fi

# Input file containing server names and port numbers (server:port)
server_list_file="$1"

# Check if the input file exists
if [ ! -f "$server_list_file" ]; then
    echo "Error: Server list file '$server_list_file' not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Loop through each line in the server list file
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Split the line into server_name and server_port
    server_name=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ':' -f 1)
    server_port=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ':' -f 2)
    
    echo "Checking server: $server_name, port: $server_port"
    
    # Run the openssl command with the server_name and server_port
    openssl s_client -connect "$server_name:$server_port" -servername "$server_name" 2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates  
    # Add a separator line between server checks
    echo "------------------------"
done < "$server_list_file"`
```

The script takes one argument file that is passed in on the commandline like so $checkopenssl.sh servers.txt
With the servers.txt file looking like the following:

```
example.local:443
test.example.org:8443
another.server.local:12345
```

The problem I have encountered is when I try to run the script it manages to break out of loop with re running the command however if I comment out the openssl command it will loop as many times as there are entries.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

I am expecting the output to look like the following:

```
Checking server: example.local, port: 443
notBefore=Mar 11 07:26:29 2023 GMT
notAfter=Apr 11 07:26:29 2024 GMT
------------------------
Checking server: test.example.org, port: 8443
notBefore=Mar 11 07:26:29 2023 GMT
notAfter=Apr 11 07:26:29 2024 GMT
------------------------
Checking server: another.server.local, port: 12345
notBefore=Mar 11 07:26:29 2023 GMT
notAfter=Apr 11 07:26:29 2024 GMT
------------------------
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["While loop stops reading after the first line in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash). Also, see [BashFAQ #89](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the first `openssl` command reads from the standard input, exhausting the input file. There might be a command line option to avoid that, or you can just redirect a noop to it:

```
: | openssl s_client -connect "$server_name:$server_port" -servername "$server_name" 2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

Comment: Alternately `< /dev/null 2> /dev/null`