# How to run scripts one at a time inside bash while loop

Tags: bash

I have the following Bash script:

```
BITRATE=
QUALITY=

while read -r BITRATE QUALITY; do
        source ./quality-test.sh -b "$BITRATE" -q "$QUALITY"
done < parameters.txt
```

I expected this while loop to run `quality-test.sh` for every line in `parameters.txt`; however, even though `parameters.txt` contains more than one line, the while loop runs only once (I've checked it by printing the values of `BITRATE` and `QUALITY` before and after the script). Why is this so? I have tried multiple ways, with or without `source`, having `source` in its own `(...)` environment etc. but nothing works. `quality-test.sh` works perfectly fine by itself, if I run it from terminal `./quality-test.sh -b ... -q ...` produces the expected results. How can I solve this? I cannot run `quality-test.sh` in the background, as multiple instances of the script would interfere with each other.

Comment: Please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) as you might be clobbering some environment variables.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for the advice, will update my script accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that `quality-test.sh` is reading from standard input, so it's consuming the rest of the file. Redirect its input so it doesn't do this.

```
while read -r BITRATE QUALITY; do
    source ./quality-test.sh -b "$BITRATE" -q "$QUALITY" < /dev/null
done < parameters.txt
```

Comment: This works! I have an implementation in `quality-test.sh` to read options using getopt, but I didn't know that classifies as stdin. What would another solution to this problem be? First reading the values for `BITRATE` and `QUALITY` in separate arrays, and then looping over the pairs of values?

Comment: No, arguments are not stdin. Do you use programs like `ssh` or `netcat` in the script?

Comment: Yes I do, I use `scp`. Could you explain how that is connected to stdin? It would help understand the issue.

Comment: `scp` shouldn't read from stdin.

Comment: We're talkiing about something that would normally read from the terminal if you run the script by itself.

Comment: if you want to I can provide the code for `quality-test.sh`, it's not long.

Comment: If it's not too long, add it to the question, otherwise upload it to pastebin.com.

Comment: [BashFAQ/089](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) may help explain.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash

Comment: @dandan13 you got an answer to the question you asked, if you have a followup question then ask a new question, don't churn this one into a [Chameleon Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: @EdMorton I think it's closely related, since it's asking why this script is reading from stdin in the script.

Comment: It is related, but the OP already accepted your answer to this one and the next one requires a different set of code, etc. and we always tell people not to significantly change their question after they got answers. It would be unfair if the OP now changed their question, someone else answered the modified version of it, and the OP unaccepted yours, which is the right answer to the question that was asked so far, in favor of theirs. The OP also stands a better chance of people reading a new question than revisiting one that's older, especially one with an accepted answer.

Comment: @tjm3772 @Barmar both of your references helped me understand the problem, `quality-test.sh` does use `ffmpeg` which consumes all standard input; from now on, I will make sure to either use `< /dev/null` or custom file descriptors when executing scripts in a loop. I agree with @EdMorton, now that I understand the reason to my problem this has turned into a completely different question (and arguably a duplicate, although I hope a useful one), so I'll stop it here. Thanks!