# Bash script for executing linux commands on remote machines using ssh key

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I want to run a script to get details of hardwares and user details from multiple remote machines by login using ssh private key. this is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the user provided a file
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "provide input file"
    echo "Usage: $0 <input_file>"
    exit 1
fi

# Read input file
input_file=$1

# Check if the file exists
if [ ! -f "$input_file" ]; then
    echo "Error: File $input_file not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Read each line from the input file
while IFS=, read -r ip_address username; do
    echo "Machine IP: $ip_address"
    # Connect to the server via SSH and execute the command
    echo "System Users:"
    ssh -i /home/subash/Desktop/privatekey "$username"@"$ip_address" "ls -l /home/ | awk 'NR >1 {print \$3}'" 2>/dev/null
    echo "---------------"
    echo "Disk details:"
    ssh -i privatekey "$username"@"$ip_address" 'lsblk -o name,model,size,ro,mountpoint,type | grep -e part -e disk' 2>/dev/null
    echo "---------------"
    echo "OPERATING SYSTEM:"
    ssh -i privatekey "$username"@"$ip_address" "cat /etc/os-release | grep '^NAME' | cut -d'=' -f2-" 2>/dev/null
    echo "---------------"  
done < "$input_file"`
```

The input file I'm providing have the ip address and the username. I have added my public key to all the machines authorized keys. when executing the script the while loop executes with the first IP and provides the expected output and exists it doesn't consider the next line of input.

The sample input file:

192.168.1.1,user1

192.168.1.2,user2

192.168.1.3,user3

If I remove the ssh command and print all the IP and user names it prints all the values from the input file.

How can I read all the IP address from the input file and get remote machine details?

Comment: And your question is ... ? Btw. You should take a look at [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)

Comment: You don't describe what's going wrong, but you may run into [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) (see ["While loop stops reading after the first line in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash)). Also, those `2>/dev/null` only redirect errors from the final command (`awk`, `grep`, and `cut`), not from `ssh` or the remote commands.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps the `ssh` commands also try to read from stdin. Try to explicitly redirect `ssh .... </dev/null`.