# how to change filenames using wildcards in bash

Tags: bash, wildcard, cp, mv

So my specific problem is I downloaded a few albums of mp3s, that don't have track numbers in their title, so they default to alphabetic sort, which is clearly not ideal. I want to be able to quickly rename them with a terminal command where I use wildcards to sort through the fluff. So I've tried this from a few angles without success, and want some guidance.

On the one hand, I want to try something like `mv *someSongN* 01-{reference original name here}`. I am not clear, in the second argument to `mv`, how I reference the original file name, but prepended with a `01-`.

The other tack I tried was to create a temporary bash variable, followed by a `mv` command. I tested this out by creating a test file without any extension -- `touch test`. I found `echo` and `mv` treat the wildcard differently. So, pretend the test file is the only in the directory beginning te-- ... `var=te*; echo $var` returns `test` but `var=te*; mv $var $var.txt` returns `te*.txt`. So what strategy do I use here. I could also do this with a graphical file manager but I've done that before and found it very tiresome.

Comment: Have you tried using the `find` command? You can run `find` with wildcards and this returns the filename which you could then set as a variable.

Comment: Do the tracks have [ID3 tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) within them?

Comment: @dawg, it looks like they do, but for whatever reason the music players I've tried just play the files thru the alphabetic sort, even while displaying the track number. At any rate, I like a little filename metadata.

Comment: You can use `Perl` or `Python` to read the ID3 tags and restore the file name (and directory for Artist/Album type organization) using the ID3 tag -- assuming it is accurate.

Comment: A quick work-around for your `var=te*; mv $var $var.txt`, could be... `var=te*; var=$(echo ${var}) ; mv $var $var.txt`     This will reset your **var** variable to what echo displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as a batch process.  Create a map file with columns fromName toName, run through a script for renaming.

```
while read a b; do mv "$a" "$b"; done < filemap
```

to create filemap, ls and paste

```
ls -1 > files; paste files files > filemap; rm files
```

and manually edit the filemap file to add required prefixes.

Comment: Where? In `ls -1`?

Comment: ah right, during the `mv` operation. I tried changing up the delimiter in `filemap` to no avail.

Comment: Do you have spaces in file names? If so, set a delimiter in paste and set IFS to that before read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the `find` command

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 = "" ]] ; then
  echo "Please run the command specifying the filename you are searching for..."
  exit
fi
for i in $(find . -type f -name "$1" | tr -d './') ; do
  echo ${i}
  mv ${i} 01-${i}
done
```

You would then run...

```
./scriptName "*someSongN*"
```

Comment: You could turn `01` into another variable that is in a loop so you would have 01-filename 02-Filename 03-Filename etc. etc.

Comment: so typically `find` outputs the current directory like `./thisisafile`, so is there a way built in to find to exclude that. I could add `cut -c 3-` to a pipe but eh

Comment: if i get the chance, I will upvote. Helpful throughout post, just found @karafka's answer slightly more efficient.

Comment: @cfye14 I modified the code to include `tr -d './'` in the for loop. this will remove the "./"

Comment: @cfye14 Not sure of a built in way yet, but I will ponder this and see if I can remove the pipe.

Comment: ah yes, `tr` is more suitable

Comment: this isn't how `tr` works. `tr -d './` will delete either of the `.` or `/` in the "set".

Comment: what would work but is a little more cumbersome is `sed 's/\.\///g'`

Comment: Hmmm. Worked perfectly on my end. I'll test this again Monday and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

when you just want to move one file, you can create (an inline) function like

```
$ mvd() { mv $1 $2$1; }
```

and use it like

```
$ mvd test.mp3 01-
```

which will move the file `test.mp3` to `01-test.mp3`.

---

By using `find`, you can do this operation on multiple files, but that will result in all files starting with only one prefix (`find . -type f -name ${pattern} -exec mvd {} ${prefix}`).

Another option is using `find . -type f -name ${pattern}` and iterate over it using `for`. Then, you can implement a counter:

```
$ i=0; for file in $(find . -type f -name ${pattern}); do mv $file $i-$file; let i+=1; done
```

Greetings
Fabian

Comment: thx. I can't quite get this to work, but I can use the function for single cases. Also it seems more work is needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321456/find-exec-a-shell-function) to use a custom bash function with find -exec.

Comment: with the for loop, how would I deal with the pattern changing?