# Read through all the files and apply a command in Linux

Tags: linux, file-io, command-line

I'm trying to do some transformation to some audio data using the `sox` command.
I'm filtering all of my 'wav' files with the following command:

```
 find . -name '*.wav'
```

Now, I would like to apply the sox command to all of the returned files, something like this:

```
find . -name '*.wav' | sox name-of-the-file-returned store-file-with-the-same-name
```

Does anyone know how would I take the returned path from the first command and give it twice as arguments to the second command, since I'm trying to run the following command:

```
sox file-name.wav file-name.wav
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find -exec a shell function in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4321456/608639), [find -exec with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5119946/608639), [Bash script to execute command on all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523415/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
find . -name '*.wav' | xargs -I@ bash -c "sox @ @"
```