# Solution for find -exec if single and double quotes already in use

Tags: bash, shell, find, double-quotes

I would like to recursively go through all subdirectories and remove the oldest two PDFs in each subfolder named "bak":

Works:

```
find . -type d -name "bak" \
  -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd" \;
```

Does not work, as the double quotes are already in use:

```
find . -type d -name "bak" \
  -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && rm "$(ls -t *.pdf | tail -2)"" \;
```

Any solution to the double quote conundrum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a double quoted string you can use backslashes to escape other double quotes, e.g.

```
find ... "rm \"\$(...)\""
```

If that is too convoluted use variables:

```
cmd='$(...)'
find ... "rm $cmd"
```

However, I think your `find -exec` has more problems than that.

- Using `{}` inside the command string `"cd '{}' ..."` is risky. If there is a `'` inside the file name things will break and might execcute unexpected commands.
- `$()` will be expanded by bash before `find` even runs. So `ls -t *.pdf | tail -2` will only be executed once in the top directory `.` instead of once for each found directory. `rm` will (try to) delete the same file for each found directory.
- `rm "$(ls -t *.pdf | tail -2)"` will not work if `ls` lists more than one file. Because of the quotes both files would be listed in one argument. Therefore, `rm` would try to delete *one* file with the name `first.pdf\nsecond.pdf`.

I'd suggest

```
cmd='cd "$1" && ls -t *.pdf | tail -n2 | sed "s/./\\\\&/g" | xargs rm'
find . -type d -name bak -exec bash -c "$cmd" -- {} \;
```

Comment: The `tr` so you can then use `xargs -0` isn't really adding any value here. If you don't know which newlines were part of a file name, you will get *file not found* both ways.

Comment: @tripleee Yes and no. I did *not* use `xargs -0` for handling files with linebreaks; that wouldn't work with `ls` anyway. I used `-0` to disable xargs' special treatment of quotes, backslashes and whitespace. With GNU xargs I could have used `-d \\n` instead. But macos' xargs doesn't offer this option. So `-0` is more portable although it might look strange here. The next best alternative would be `... | sed 's/./\\&/g' | xargs rm` I think.

Comment: @tripleee How do you know macOS' xargs doesn't have the `-0` option? I couldn't test it, but the [macOS man page for xargs](https://ss64.com/osx/xargs.html) lists `-0` as the very first option. I took the `tr | xargs` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589977/6770384). There is a comment saying *"`this option is not available`"*, however, *this* has to reference `-d` (look at the answers edit history the date of the comment). Anyways, I edited my answer to use the posix conform `sed | xargs`.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused - macOS `xargs` does have the `-0` option. (I was mixing it up with `find` which doesn't have `-print0` so using `xargs -0` for one of its primary use cases is harder on macOS.)

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitely asking for `find -exec`. Usually I would just concatenate `find -exec find -delete` but in your case only two files should be deleted. Therefore the only method is running subshell. Socowi already gave nice solution, however if your file names do not contain tabulator or newlines, another workaround is `find while read` loop.

This will sort files by mtime

```
find . -type d -iname 'bak' | \
while read -r dir;
  do
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.pdf' -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | \
    sort | head -n2 | \
    cut -f2- | \
    while read -r file;
      do
        rm "$file";
    done;
done;
```

The above `find while read` loop as "one-liner"

```
find . -type d -iname 'bak' | while read -r dir; do find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.pdf' -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort | head -n2 | cut -f2- | while read -r file; do rm "$file"; done; done;
```

`find while read` loop can also handle NUL terminated file names. However `head` can not handle this, so I did improve other answers and made it work with nontrivial file names (only GNU + bash)

---

replace ***'realpath'*** with `rm`

```
#!/bin/bash

rm_old () {
  find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname \*.$2 -printf "%T+\t%p\0" | sort -z | sed -zn 's,\S*\t\(.*\),\1,p' | grep -zim$3 \.$2$ | xargs -0r realpath
}

export -f rm_old

find -type d -iname bak -execdir bash -c 'rm_old "{}" pdf 2' \;
```

However `bash -c` might still exploitable, to make it more secure let `stat %N` do the quoting

```
#!/bin/bash

rm_old () {
  local dir="$1"

# we don't like eval
#  eval "dir=$dir"

  # this works like eval
  dir="${dir#?}"
  dir="${dir%?}"
  dir="${dir//"'$'\t''"/$'\011'}"
  dir="${dir//"'$'\n''"/$'\012'}"
  dir="${dir//$'\047'\\$'\047'$'\047'/$'\047'}"

  find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname \*.$2 -printf '%T+\t%p\0' | sort -z | sed -zn 's,\S*\t\(.*\),\1,p' | grep -zim$3 \.$2$ | xargs -0r realpath
}

find -type d -iname bak -exec stat -c'%N' {} + | while read -r dir; do rm_old "$dir" pdf 2; done
```

Comment: The `while read` could easily and more idiomatically be replaced with `xargs`

Comment: @triplee thx have added `-execdir` `xargs` with `find` instead of `ls` for handling nontrivial file names. got the idea from here, there it looks less ugly https://stackoverflow.com/a/26349346

Answer (score 1):

You have a more fundamental problem; because you are using the weaker double quotes around the entire script, the `$(...)` command substitution will be interpreted by the shell which parses the `find` command, not by the `bash` shell you are starting, which will only receive a static string containing the result from the command substitution.

If you switch to single quotes around the script, you get *most* of it right; but that would still fail if the file name you find contains a double quote (just like your attempt would fail for file names with single quotes). The proper fix is to pass the matching files as command-line arguments to the `bash` subprocess.

But a better fix still is to use `-execdir` so that you don't have to pass the directory name to the subshell at all:

```sh
find . -type d -name "bak" \
  -execdir bash -c 'ls -t *.pdf | tail -2 | xargs -r rm' \;
```

This could stll fail in funny ways because you are [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) which is inherently buggy.