# Linux Hash Values

Tags: linux

I'm working on an assignment, and the directions say "Generate a MD5 hash value of your text1 and save this hash value as text1-md5." I know the command to generate the hash is md5sum text1 but how do I get that to save to the text1-md5? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the command like you can for any linux command:

```
md5sum text1 > text1-md5
```

However you might want to [cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) the output as in addition to the md5 hash md5sum outputs the filename. Alternatively read [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3679296/812912).