# get checksum based on a string in shell script

Tags: shell

when i use

```
echo -n "$str" |sha224sum
```

it gets me the checksum ends with "-"

how to get the checksum without it ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only get hash value using md5sum (without filename)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679296/only-get-hash-value-using-md5sum-without-filename)

Answer (score 1):

Cut the first field:

```
$ echo -n "$str" | sha224sum  | cut -d' ' -f1
23097d223405d8228642a477bda255b32aadbce4bda0b3f7e36c9da7
```