# sed - how to do regex groups using sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Is there anyway you can do regex match group using sed like java regex pattern/match/group?

if i have string like

```
test-artifact-201251-balbal-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

how do I use sed just to get the result like:

```
test-artifact-0.1-SNASHOT.jar
```

I am wondering does sed allow you to do something like java regex, you define the pattern like:

```
([a-z]*-[a-z]*-)([0-9]*-)([a-z]*-)([.]*SNAPSHOT.jar)
```

and then you can get the results as an array like:

```
test-artifact-
201251-
balbal-
0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777579/how-to-output-only-captured-groups-with-sed

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You have to escape parentheses to group expressions:

```
\([a-z]*-[a-z]*-\)\([0-9]*-\)\([a-z]*-\)\([.]*SNAPSHOT.jar\)
```

And use them with `\1`, `\2`, etc.

---

**EDIT**: Also note just before `SNAPSHOT` that `[.]` will not match. Inside brackets `.` is literal. It should be `[0-9.-]*`

Comment: With GNU `sed` you can avoid all the escaped parenthesis by using extended regular expressions. Use the `-r` switch to do this.

Comment: `-E` also works in GNU to not need to escape parens.

Answer (score 25):

This is what Birei and Thor mean:

```
sed -r "s/([a-z]*-[a-z]*-)([0-9]*-)([a-z]*-)(.*)/\1\n\2\n\3\n\4/"
```

Output:

```
test-artifact-
201251-
balbal-
0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

infact for those regular string, awk could save you  from grouping.  :)

you just give the part index number you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"}{print $1,$2,$5,$6}'
```

output:

```
kent$  echo "test-artifact-201251-balbal-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"|awk 'BEGIN{FS="-";OFS="-"}{print $1,$2,$5,$6}'
test-artifact-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are searching for an easier way I guess this might be of your help! :)

```
echo "est-artifact-201251-balbal-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" | cut -d- -f1,2,5,6
```

"-" used as delimeter
and fields 1,2,5,6 are printed.

Note: This would require you to know the exact position of the field.