# Regex in sed to match a subpath in a path with capturing groups

Tags: bash, sed, path

I have a list of [dictionaries](https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries), made by two files named `index` with extension `{aff,dic}` like

```
dictionaries/dictionaries/bg_BG/index.dic
dictionaries/dictionaries/ca_ES/index.dic
dictionaries/dictionaries/cs_CZ/index.dic
dictionaries/dictionaries/da_DK/index.dic
...
dictionaries/dictionaries/bg_BG/index.aff
dictionaries/dictionaries/ca_ES/index.aff
dictionaries/dictionaries/cs_CZ/index.aff
dictionaries/dictionaries/da_DK/index.aff
```

and I want to copy them in a different folder, but naming each of the by the subpath like `it_IT` in order to have

```
myDicts/it_IT.dic
myDicts/it_IT.acc
```

I came out with this inline

```
for file in dictionaries/dictionaries/**/*.{dic,aff}; do echo ${file}; done
```

that lists the files in these folders, having in `$file` the `for...loop` variable `dictionaries/dictionaries/da_DK/index.aff`.

So using `sed` I was able to selected (in exclusion) those patterns like

```
sed 's:[a-z][a-z][_-][A-Z][A-Z]::';
```

so having

```
for file in dictionaries/dictionaries/**/*.{dic,aff}; do echo ${file} | sed 's:[a-z][a-z][_-][A-Z][A-Z]::'; done
```

that this time will print out

```
dictionaries/dictionaries//index.dic
dictionaries/dictionaries//index.dic
dictionaries/dictionaries//index.dic
...
dictionaries/dictionaries//index.aff
dictionaries/dictionaries//index.aff
dictionaries/dictionaries//index.aff
```

For my understanding I know that `sed` to print out the capture group needs to specify the captured group and the non capturing part - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777579/how-to-output-only-captured-groups-with-sed)

But I was not able to figure out how to achieve this in order to have in `$file` at the end

```
bg_BG.acc
ca_ES.acc
da_DK.acc
...
bg_BG.dic
ca_ES.dic
da_DK.dic
```

where the extension `{acc,dic}` should be added as well.
I need to execute this command inline for scripting reasons.

**[UPDATE]**
Thanks to the answer below I came out with this solution

```
for file in dictionaries/dictionaries/**/*.{dic,aff}; do echo $file | sed 's:.*\([a-z][a-z][_-][A-Z][A-Z]\)/index\(.*\):cp & myDicts/\1\2:' | sh; done
```

that does its job:

```
$ ls myDicts/
bg_BG.aff cs_CZ.aff de_AT.aff de_DE.aff en_AU.aff en_GB.aff en_ZA.aff eu_ES.aff gl_ES.aff it_IT.aff mn_MN.aff nl_NL.aff pl_PL.aff pt_PT.aff ru_RU.aff sl_SI.aff sv_SE.aff uk_UA.aff
bg_BG.dic cs_CZ.dic de_AT.dic de_DE.dic en_AU.dic en_GB.dic en_ZA.dic eu_ES.dic gl_ES.dic it_IT.dic mn_MN.dic nl_NL.dic pl_PL.dic pt_PT.dic ru_RU.dic sl_SI.dic sv_SE.dic uk_UA.dic
ca_ES.aff da_DK.aff de_CH.aff el_GR.aff en_CA.aff en_US.aff es_ES.aff fr_FR.aff hr_HR.aff lb_LU.aff nb_NO.aff nn_NO.aff pt_BR.aff ro_RO.aff sk_SK.aff sr_RS.aff tr-TR.aff vi_VN.aff
ca_ES.dic da_DK.dic de_CH.dic el_GR.dic en_CA.dic en_US.dic es_ES.dic fr_FR.dic hr_HR.dic lb_LU.dic nb_NO.dic nn_NO.dic pt_BR.dic ro_RO.dic sk_SK.dic sr_RS.dic tr-TR.dic vi_VN.dic
```

There is only one pitfall that is it does not capture these path patterns

```
dictionaries/dictionaries/ca_ES-valencia/
dictionaries/dictionaries/sr_RS-Latn
dictionaries/dictionaries/ca_ES-valencia/
dictionaries/dictionaries/sr_RS-Latn/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a way:

```
echo dictionaries/dictionaries/da_DK/index.aff |
  sed 's:.*\([^/]\+\)/index\(\..*\):\1\2:'
```

output:

```
da_DK.aff
```

however, there's a faster way than a `for` loop:

```
find dictionaries/dictionaries -name "index.dic" -or -name "index.aff" |
  sed 's:dictionaries/dictionaries/\([^/]\+\)/index\(\..*\):mv & myDicts/\1\2:'
```

if that produces the commands you want, pipe it to `sh`:

```
mkdir myDicts
find dictionaries/dictionaries -name "index.dic" -or -name "index.aff" |
  sed 's:dictionaries/dictionaries/\([^/]\+\)/index\(\..*\):mv & myDicts/\1\2:' |
  sh
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I have missed some patterns like `dictionaries/dictionaries/ca_ES-valencia/index.aff`, `dictionaries/dictionaries/sr_RS-Latn/index.dic`, `dictionaries/dictionaries/sr_RS-Latn/index.aff`, etc. How to add this group as well?

Comment: btw the first command it works, for some reason I get a `sh: line 72: dictionaries/dictionaries/tr-TR/index.dic: Permission denied` in the `find` pipe to `sh`.

Comment: Tried this way: `for file in dictionaries/dictionaries/**/*.{dic,aff}; do $file | sed 's:.*\([a-z][a-z][_-][A-Z][A-Z]\)/index\(.*\):cp & myDicts/\1\2:'; done` but now `permission denied` as well.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo: 4 `....` instead of 5 `.....`. i've fixed it to handle e.g. `ca_ES-valencia` as well.