# Extract pdf from html using sed

Tags: html, regex, linux, bash, sed

I am writing a bash script that extracts pdf files from html and downloads it. Here is the line of code that extracts:

```
 curl -s https://info.uqam.ca/\~privat/INF1070/ |
              sed 's/.*href="//' |
              sed 's/".*//' |
              sed '/^[^\.]/d' |
              sed '/\.[^p][^d][^f]$/d' |
              sed '/^$/d' |
              sed '/\/$/d'
```

Result:

```
./07b-reseau.pdf
./07a-reseau.pdf
./06b-script.pdf
./06a-script.pdf
./05-processus.pdf
./04b-regex.pdf
./181-quiz1-g1-sujet.pdf
./03b-fichiers-solution.pdf
./04a-regex.pdf
./03d-fichiers.pdf
./03c-fichiers.pdf
./03b-fichiers.pdf
./03a-fichiers.pdf
./02-shell.pdf
./01-intro.pdf
./01-intro.pdf
./02-shell.pdf
./03a-fichiers.pdf
./03b-fichiers.pdf
./03b-fichiers-solution.pdf
./03c-fichiers.pdf
./03d-fichiers.pdf
./04a-regex.pdf
./04b-regex.pdf
./05-processus.pdf
./06a-script.pdf
./06b-script.pdf
./07a-reseau.pdf
./07b-reseau.pdf
./181-quiz1-g1-sujet.pdf
```

It's working fine but I was wondering if there is a better way **(always by using sed)** to do this with less sed commands.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes there is.  You could build a regex that does all those steps in one sed command.  Now it is cost / benefit that will justify if you do it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate your original question into something like [How to output only captured groups with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2778096/3278362). This one-liner should do the trick for you:

```
curl -s https://info.uqam.ca/\~privat/INF1070/ | sed -rn 's/.*href="(.*\.pdf)".*$/\1/p'
```

which produces the desired output.

Where the combination of the `-n` option (not to print) and the `p` flag (print what is matched) will print only the lines where substitution take place based on the regex `.*href="(.*\.pdf)".*$`. The value of the *href* attribute (the capture group in parenthesis) is back referenced with `\1`, thus the whole line is replaced with it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\n/!s/href="(\.[^"]*\.pdf)"/\n\1\n/g;/\`[^\n]*\.pdf$/MP;D' file
```

This puts each pdf file into a separate line (multiple lines within a line) and only prints out a line that ends in `.pdf`.